# align text in a span tag

Tags: css

I am trying to setup a arrow navigation where I have a next and previous button.
Needs to be supported in IE 7 and up.

For the next I want the background image to show to the right of the next text.
Then of the previous button I want the text to show to the left side of the previous text.
I thought this would be easy but I just spent 2 hours on it.

Anyone can help with this before I go crazy.

```
<span class="next">
<a href="#">Next Month</a>
August
</span>


<span class="prev">
<a href="#">Previous Month</a>
June
</span>
```

In my css I have this for the left button and it works great.

```
.prev a, .next a {
    background: url("sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -200px -5px transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -9999em;
 }

.prev {
  float: left; 
}

.next {
  float: right; 
}

.next a {
   background-position: -200px -18px; 
}
```

Comment: Just updated it to show IE7 and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chapsterj; first `span` is an `inline` element so, define `display:block` in his css . Second there is not need for `text-indent` & Third you can do it without extra span tag . Do like this

```
<a href="#" class="next">Next Month</a>
<a href="#" class="prev">Previous Month</a>
```

css:

```
a.prev, a.next{
    background: url("sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -200px -5px transparent;
    display:block;
    height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

.prev {
  float: left;
  padding-right:40px; 
}

.next{
   background-position: -200px -18px; 
   float: right;
   padding-left:40px;
}
```

Comment: That's great sandeep but I also need to show the month to the left and right of the image background in the a tag. The image background is just a circle with an arrow in it. The only reason I had next month and previous month in the a tag was in case the user had images turned off in there browser. this way they could see the hidden text if the images were turned off. I still need the span to store my month text.